# Problems INSTALLING R package (GMMAT)

Tags: r, package

I am new into R and I am trying to install a package called GMMAT from github and I am getting the following error. My R Studio Version is **1.3.1093** and my console is R version **3.5.1**

```
library(devtools)
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(c("SeqArray", "SeqVarTools"))
install.packages('GMMAT')
```

Error when installing GMMAT

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [GMMAT.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘GMMAT’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/GMMAT’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘GMMAT’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/gt/7jl13g8n56l0mz23wq8hvzn40000gn/T/RtmpOkOnJJ/downloaded_packages’
```

I also get errors when loading the biocManager and SeqArray...

```
> library(BiocManager)
Bioconductor version 3.8 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Bioconductor version '3.8' is out-of-date; the current release version '3.14' is available with R version
  '4.1'; see https://bioconductor.org/install

Attaching package: ‘BiocManager’

The following object is masked from ‘package:devtools’:

    install

Warning message:
In get(results[[i]], packages[[i]]) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
> library(SeqArray)
Loading required package: gdsfmt
Warning message:
package ‘SeqArray’ was built under R version 3.5.2
```

Comment: You don’t have the development tools to compile from sources. You also have an ancient version of R and are unlikely to gent. Success with installation of the compiler tool set.

Comment: So do I essentially need to update my R to the latest version?

Comment: Update R (and, while you're at it, RStudio, too) and try again. The package installed just fine for me using the latest versions of the tools.

Comment: Clarification. The second section of code did not have errors. The apparent errors in the first section came about because of the lack of the proper toolset for that version of R. You would have needed a C compiler and a Fortran compiler that were being used when R 3.5.1 was current, as well as XCode and the command line tools properly "aligned" in time with that version. Those might have been available at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ , but I don't know if the Mac R website has the necessary instructions for setting up your system environment.  Maybe Internet Archive

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies. The error was solved once I updated my R and R studio to the latest versions. As well as my mac OS to the latest one. Thnaks everyone.